# How to wait for an asynchronous method

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I need to return the value `uId`. I am getting the correct value in the first log statement inside the `onResponse()` function. But when it comes to the return statement it returns **null**.

I think that onResponse() is running on another thread. If so, how can I make the **getNumber()** function wait till the **onResponse()** function finishes execution.(Like thread.join())

Or is there any other solution?

code :

```
String uId;
public String getNumber() {

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<TopLead> call = apiInterface.getTopLead();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<TopLead>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TopLead> call, Response<TopLead> response) {
            String phoneNumber;
            TopLead topLead = response.body();
            if (topLead != null) {
                phoneNumber = topLead.getPhoneNumber().toString();
                uId = topLead.getUId().toString();
                //dispaly the correct value of uId
                Log.i("PHONE NUMBER, UID", phoneNumber +", " + uId);
                onCallCallback.showToast("Calling " + phoneNumber);
            } else {
                onCallCallback.showToast("Could not load phone number");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TopLead> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    //output: Return uid null
    Log.i("Return"," uid" + uId);
    return uId;
```

Comment: you should read up on scopes and order of execution. the return statement runs before your uId value is set

Comment: Maybe the `Callback` gets executed later, such that at the moment in time the thread of execution reaches the `return`, the `Callback` was not yet executed.

Comment: Your method call is asynchronous. The best way IMO is to make the `getNumber()` method asynchronous : instead of returning a value, make `getNumber()` accept a callback method and call it at the end of `onResponse()`.

Comment: I understand that it is in another thread. I need to know whether there is any way to make the main thread wait till the onResponse() is finished. Like we do thread.join() in java

Comment: @AbhijithK - usually you show something indicating to the user that there is some background work being done (e.g. a progress bar). But you should not block the UI. You may disable certain UI elements until your callback (see answers) gets the desired data. But "waiting" would freeze the UI, and that's taboo. Take a look at the [guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html) to see which kind of behavior is expected.

Comment: Try using a boolean value to check whether the function has ended.

Comment: Have you tried using Executer.

Comment: @AbhijithK spin up a callback and

Comment: @abhijith-k use the method from within the callback

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your method performs an async request. So the action "return uId; " doesn't wait until your request finishes because they are on different threads.

There are several solutions I can suggest

1. Use an interface callback

   ```
    public void getNumber(MyCallback callback) {
      ...
       phoneNumber = topLead.getPhoneNumber().toString();
       callback.onDataGot(phoneNumber);
    }
   ```

Your callback interface

```
     public interface MyCallback {

        void onDataGot(String number);
     }
```

And finally, calling the method

```
getNumber(new MyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDataGot(String number) {
    // response
    }
});
```

2. When using **Kotlin** (I think it's time for you to use Kotlin instead of Java :))

   ```
   fun getNumber(onSuccess: (phone: String) -> Unit) {
     phoneNumber = topLead.getPhoneNumber().toString()
     onSuccess(phoneNumber)
   }
   ```

Calling the method

```
    getNumber {
      println("telephone $it")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I could not understand the answer of @David I had to come up with a solution myself. I had to receive data from the network using the library `OkHttp3`. To solve this problem I used `LiveData`.

```
fun getText(): LiveData<String> {
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var result = ""
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            result = e.toString()
            liveData.postValue(result)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            result = response.body.toString()
            liveData.postValue(result)
        }
    })
    return liveData
}
```

Once you have the LiveData object we can observe it:

```
getText().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Received $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you wanted uId and you are not getting it. Your function `getNumber()` executes TopDown but the request you are making is Asychronous, **runs on a different thread**. So at the time that you are returning `uId`, there is no value in `uId`. Out of the callbacks that `call.enqueue` has, and I mean `onResponse()` and `onFailure()`, there is no way you can get `uId` in `onFailure`, that is obvious but it is not so obvious that you will get `uId` in `onResponse()'. 
From the javadoc for Retrofit:

> onResponse
>       `void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response)`
>
> Invoked for a received HTTP response.
>       Note: An HTTP response may still indicate an application-level failure such as a 404 or 500. Call Response.isSuccessful() to determine if the response indicates success.

So in `onResponse` you will still need to put some code to ensure you are getting `uId` and then only return it. And do not return the `uId` directly, set to some string (global) and access it after making sure it is available.

So change your code like::

```
public void getNumber() {

ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<TopLead> call = apiInterface.getTopLead();
call.enqueue(new Callback<TopLead>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<TopLead> call, Response<TopLead> response) {
        if(response.isSuccesful(){
            String phoneNumber;
        TopLead topLead = response.body();
        if (topLead != null) {
            phoneNumber = topLead.getPhoneNumber().toString();
            uId = topLead.getUId().toString();
            //dispaly the correct value of uId
            Log.i("PHONE NUMBER, UID", phoneNumber +", " + uId);
            onCallCallback.showToast("Calling " + phoneNumber);
            //output: Return uid 
           Log.i("Return"," uid" + uId); 

        } else {
            onCallCallback.showToast("Could not load phone number");
        }
        } else{
            Log.e("in ", " response is not successful" )
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<TopLead> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

This still runs on a different thread, so `uId` will be set after some time. Once set you can use the value. You can also use `Synchronous` request if you want to run on the main thread and get the `uId` using `call.execute().body();` which returns `TopLead` object and then you can get `uId` from ther e using `topLead.getUId.toString()`.

I hope it helps, do ask in comments if you need clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Don't return the value. Because AsyncTask is a separate one runs outside the normal process.

So please create a method with the parameters and pass your values to that method.